# Magento price zero

Tags: rest, magento, magento2

I can successfully add item to the cart using this rest API from my APP.

> POST /V1/carts/mine/items

However the item is added with a price of ZERO.

The new quote was created from the APP using this API.

> POST /V1/carts/mine

But when I try to add an item from magento web the price is showing correct value. I am using magento 2. This is the post data.

```
    {
  "cart_item": {
    "productOption": {
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "configurableItemOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "131",
            "optionValue": 4
          },
          {
            "optionId": "90",
            "optionValue": 32
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "productType": "configurable",
    "qty": 1,
    "quoteId": "88",
    "sku": "ONE_TIME_PRODUCT"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Magento 1 or 2? Can you please share an example of your request data?

Comment: Am using magento 2

{
  "cart_item": {
    "productOption": {
      "extensionAttributes": {
        "configurableItemOptions": [
          {
            "optionId": "131",
            "optionValue": 4
          },
          {
            "optionId": "90",
            "optionValue": 32
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "productType": "configurable",
    "qty": 1,
    "quoteId": "88",
    "sku": "ONE_TIME_PRODUCT"
  }
}